Delphi and WinAPI.mmsystem
I would like to know how to stop a playing sound that I have initiated asynchronously using the sndPlaySound() function:
sndPlaySound(PWideChar('MyWaveFile.wav'), SND_NODEFAULT OR SND_ASYNC);

I have tried using the waveOutClose() function but this is never successful.  It always returns code 5, which I think is MMSYSERR_INVALHANDLE.  This is regardless what I use for hWaveOut.

This is answered in the sndPlaySound documentation: "To terminate an asynchronously played sound, call sndPlaySound with lpszSound set to NULL."
